# undefined method `variant' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to upload photos for an article so I have Active Storage turned on and three mini_magick and image_processing gems installed. I also have in the article model two methods in charge of resizing the photo, I also have the relationship with the photos

```
def photo_as_thumbnail(photo)
    photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [300, 300]).processed
end
def photo_as_icon(photo)
    photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [50, 50]).processed
end
```

In the controller I added the photos in the parameters

```
private
    def product_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:name, :description, :price, photos: [])
    end
```

To display the photos in the view I use the following:

```
<% @product.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= link_to image_tag(@product.photo_as_thumbnail(photo)), photo %>
<% end %>
```

When listing the items and creating them, it gives the following error:

```
undefined method 'variant' for nil:NilClass
photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [50, 50]).processed

def photo_as_icon(photo)
photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [50, 50]).processed
end
```

But when editing an article it does not give any error and I can upload and view the images as well as save the changes I make in the different fields

Enabling Active Storage and installed two gems mini_magick and image_processing and installed imagemagick.
Adding the methods for resizing in the model I hoped to use it to put some smaller photos

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! I notice that in the code that works, you use `photos` but in the code you don't work you use `photo`. Is there an association with multiple photos? If so, do you have a way of telling the variant code which photo to use? (and also what to do if there aren't any photos to use)

Comment: @TarynEast `photo` is a block scope local variable in the block passed to `#each`  which is then passed into a instance method in the Product model  (which is a kind of odd solution but not the source of the error). I suspect that the actual issue is that `@product.photos` contains one or more elements that are `nil`. But this question doesn't have enough debugging details to for us to know why.

Comment: Ah thanks, yeah I missed that from the code above. Must've scanned right over it. Cheers for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, As max points out in a comment above, for some reason there are nils in `@product.photos` which are then getting passed into you method.

Now that's a bigger problem and you should probably dig into why that's happening for you. For that, you may need to look at the code that is part of the form for a product, or how you are saving photos.

But for the meantime, you can stop the bug with a nil check - which can be done in one of two ways:

You could check for nils in the individual photo methods eg:

```
def photo_as_thumbnail(photo)
    photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [300, 300]).processed if photo
end
def photo_as_icon(photo)
    photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [50, 50]).processed if photo
end
```

check each time for a nil - which will work, but feels a bit duplicated. plus if you changed the outer code to something like:

```
<% @product.photos.compact.each do |photo| %>
    <div class="photo">
      <%= link_to image_tag(@product.photo_as_thumbnail(photo)), photo %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

would mean that for any nils you'd end up with a bunch of empty divs like:

```
    <div class="photo">
    </div>
```

So my preference would be not to feed nils into the loop in the first place. But try compacting the array before you pass it in:

```
<% @product.photos.compact.each do |photo| %>
    <%= link_to image_tag(@product.photo_as_thumbnail(photo)), photo %>
<% end %>
```

Here `compact` will remove any nils before passing them to the link. It might still bork if `@product.photos` is itself nil, so use it with "try" which will only call the method if the thing it's being called on (AKA the receiver) isn't also nil:

```
<% @product.photos.try(:compact).each do |photo| %>
    <%= link_to image_tag(@product.photo_as_thumbnail(photo)), photo %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that there are products without photos.

Comment: yes, and this variant of the code will make sure that it doesn't bork on them :)
Instead it will just skip the nils. If you have products with no photos at all, you just check for that first with `if @product.photos.present?`